# file_get_html() not working in Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have some PHP code working perfectly in local and also in the web (with a non SSL hosting). I get file contents with `file_get_html(url)` and everything works OK.

The problem comes when I try to run this code in Google App Engine. The function `file_get_html()` doesn't work.

The following code shows nothing between **BEGIN** and **END**:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

include './simple_html_dom.php';

$sitioweb = file_get_html("http://www.bolsamadrid.es/esp/aspx/Mercados/Precios.aspx?indice=ESI100000000");

echo "BEGIN<hr>";
echo $sitioweb;
echo "<hr>END";
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: when i check on this site http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ they give this code to dump the html  "file_get_html('foo')->plaintext;" so maybe $sitioweb->plaintext will work ?

Comment: Works locally but not in Google App Engine. The problem is not simple_html_dom library, I have plenty of staff done with it; the problem is that I can't use it in App Engine because I can't get the content of an external web.

Comment: what happen if you just do a file_get_content ?

Comment: file_get_content doesn't work either in app eng :-(

Comment: then it's surly about the setting in google app engine, you don't have any errors ?

Comment: I don't have any errors. It is for sure the setting in google app engine but I don't have idea, I can't find where I could configure these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I use `curl` instead `file_get_html`.

Code that doesn't work for me in Google App Engine:

```
$sitioweb = file_get_html("http://www.bolsamadrid.es/esp/aspx/Mercados/Precios.aspx?indice=ESI100000000");
```

Code that work perfectly for me in Google App Engine:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.bolsamadrid.es/esp/aspx/Mercados/Precios.aspx?indice=ESI100000000');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$sitioweb = str_get_html($str);
```

It is a bit more verbose but works :-)

Answer (score 0):

PHP cURL has to be installed to get it to work:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Then restart the apache server.